# Deleting bulk files with the same extension while preserving files with the same extension

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem "I:\TEMP_Dir_SSN\" | %{
    if($_.name -ne "fullpath.txt" -or $_.name -ne "SSN_FILES.txt"){
        remove-item $_.fullname
    }
}
```

There are two files in the same directory that I don't want to delete. I want to delete all but two .txt files. They need to be preserved in the same directory. However, the rest is garbage and can be removed.

Comment: `fullname` will never be `fullpath.txt` - it will be `I:\TEMP_DIR_SSN\fullpath.txt`.  Consider using `name` for both.

Comment: I tried that and it deletes all the files still. That's why I went to fullname. I know there is a way to preserve two files with the same extension.

Comment: Regardless, the logic there was flawed.  That would never (ever) skip the `Remove-Item` portion.  Can you [edit] your question to clarify?  Are you wanting to preserve **any** file with a `.txt` extension, or **only** these two specifically named files?

Comment: only these two specific named files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Exclude` parameter to exclude the files:

```
Get-ChildItem "I:\TEMP_Dir_SSN" -Exclude "fullpath.txt","SSN_FILES.txt" | Remove-Item
```

Comment: very nice inclusion with the -exclude. Didn't know that was a parameter with GCI, thank you.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) is your friend :) You can be very precise when using `Include` and `Exclude` combos too.

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize Where-Object in your pipeline to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
Get-ChildItem "I:\TEMP_Dir_SSN\" |
  Where-Object { (($_.Name -notlike 'fullpath.txt') -and
                  ($_.Name -notlike 'SSN_FILES.txt')) } |
  Remove-Item
```

Just a note for more terse reading/writing, you can use the built-in alias `GCI` and `Where`

Comment: I will try this out. I figured out a working solution that is just as good. I just copy them over before removing them. Doesn't take up any extra time. A few resources, but the file sizes are so small it hardly matters.

Comment: @schnipdip Just a note about PowerShell logical operators, -and will only evaluate one half of the comparison if the first one is false, and -or will only evaluate one half of the comparison if the first one is true.

[about_Logical_Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Nice, +1. Removed `$_` at the end as it results in errors when testing. `Remove-Item` accepts pipeline input so it's not required. Consider using `-ne` instead of `-notlike` as the filenames are exactly known.

Comment: @gms0ulman Thanks, I almost forgot I was dealing with a pipeline (mostly copied his example)!  I've had limited success using the exact operators (ne/eq) with string inputs and have been in the habit in my work to use wildcards and the like/notlike operators